# Retrieving VersionData with standard REST API

Tags: javascript, contentversion, base64, character-encoding, amazon-s3

I am trying to retrieve VersionData with a standard REST API call from a VisualForce Page a then upload it to a S3 bucket but end up with corrupted files. I believe this is an encoding problem on the client side as plain text or CSVs work like a charm. I can upload VersionData from Apex but there are heap and request size limitations so I need to send the data from the client.

[image]
This is the call and returned string, I tried changing mimeType and encoding on both sides (SF call and S3 upload) with no luck.

Any ideas how to properly process images or pdf files? Thanks a lot

Comment: The image on the left is the retrieved data? It's been a while since I've read a GIF file, but it looks about right to me. The only problem is that your code is choosing to show it as plain text instead of as an image; you might just be missing an `img` tag. What happens if you render it as a link? Can you click on it to download/open it? Does it look right?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply! Yes that is the data - I just appended that string to the DOM as plain text to see what it looks like. To display/download it I would need to encode it to base64 first, right? That's the trouble - I am not sure how to encoded the retrieved data as some of those characters are not legal latin chars.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was jQuery ajax method.

Files should not be treated as strings. I solved the problem by leaving jQuery's ajax as I did not succeed to request a response type. By switching to plain JS and making a GET call (XMLHttpRequest) with response type set to blob I received an Object, instead of a string. Base64 string can be then retreived using JS FileReader.

XMLHttpRequest with responseType set to "blob" solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The result is a binary blob. Appending it the way you did obviously results in garbled output, because you're looking at a raw set of bytes, not characters in a string. Given your current code, you should be able to do something like this:

```
$('#accountList').append(
  '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,"+btoa(result)+'" />');
```

Your browser should take care of the rest for you.

Comment: btoa cannot be used as the response contains non-Latin1 characters. However, overriding mimeType to use different encoding produces "readable" and encodable string but it seems to corrupt the data.

Comment: @PetrVav Well, I do know you should not be playing with encoding. Encoding is a feature of *text* streams. Binary streams do not know the concept of encoding. I think that's where you're going down the wrong path.

Comment: I agree, but do you have any other idea how to process the response? btoa cannot be applied on the response as it is and other "custom" base64 encoding methods I tried produce corrupted data.